# Cannot upload macro excel file

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, excel

I have a problem with uploading macro (xlsm) files in a SharePoint Foundation 2013 Site collection. Strange is that on other SharePoint site collections which are on separate server farms, it works normally. Could the problem be that the version of our SharePoint is too old which is 15.0.4420.1017 and the other one has a newer version.This type of file is not blocked in the central administration so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Edit: 
I already checked the site for blocked types and the xlsm file type is not in the list. I will post a screenshot: 
[image: Upload error]

Error translation: The URL Freigegebene Dokumente/Test_1.xlms is not invalid. "Freigegebene Dokumente" is the name of the document library and "Test_1" is the file.
Perhaps it refers to a nonexistent file or folder outside the current page. Could the problem be the disk space for SharePoint since we have now less then 1 GB of free space? I also checked the Log files and at the time of the upload there were only w3wp.exe events.

Answer (score 1):

"Blocked file types" can be set differently in each instance of SharePoint that you're running -- it's likely that the environment giving you issues does not allow upload of files with that extension.

You can view and/or adjust blocked file types in SharePoint from within Central Administration by following the instructions here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262496.aspx

> **To add or remove blocked file types by using Central Administration**
>
> 1. Verify that you have the following administrative credentials: You must be a farm administrator on the server
> 2. In Central Admniistration, click **Security.**
> 3. On the **Security** page, in the **General Security** section, click **Define blocked file types**.
> 4. On the **Blocked File Types** page, if you want to change the selected web application, on the **Web Application** menu, click **Change Web Application**. Use the **Select Web Application** page to select a web application.
> 5. Do one of the following:
>
>    - To block an additional file type, scroll to the bottom of the **Type each file name extension on a seperate line** text box, type in the file name extension that you want to block, and then click **OK**.
>    - To stop blocking a file type, select a file type from the list, press the Delete key, and then click **OK**.